# Как в edit text писать на русском

Tags: android-edittext

Для себя делаю базу данных англо-русских слов. Подскажите как в приложении в EditText писать на русском или на разных языках. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду на эмуляторе?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Если на эмуляторе не пишется, то вам поможет включение в настройках эмулятора (в списке эмуляторов) использования виртуальной клавиатуры.